# how can i use MySQL installed with WAMP Server in my java program

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server-2005, wamp

i already installed MySQL with Wamp server,now i am developing java server program in my local machine,i need to know is it possible to use the same MySQL to my java program also,if possible how(how can i create database,how can i connect to database etc)?please help me

Comment: Is this not the subject of every basic Java and mySQl tutorial?

Comment: i mean is mysql installed with wamp is only for php development or not,can i use it as normal mysql which install seperatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you may be missing, if you have a Java JDK installed, will be the [JDBC driver](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) for MySQL. Then you can work with MySQL, since the MySQL you get from WAMP is OK.

WAMP includes Apache and PHP which are irrelevant for the Java-MySQL connection, unless you want to use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) instead of [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), in order to manipulate your MySQL. I still think that if you install the components you work with straight from their websites, you get exactly what you need, you have latest versions and a better overall overview.